# How should I use a third-party package in my package if I need to edit the third-party package's `setup.py`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

I have a fork `my_foo` of a third-party package `foo`. All I did was add three lines of Python to `foo`'s `setup.py`, since `foo` does not pass the correct flags to `gcc`.

What's the best way to use the fork `my_foo` in my package `bar`? Should I create a subpackage `bar.my_foo`? Should I upload `my_foo` to PyPI and do `install_requires = ["my_foo"]` in the `setup.py` of `bar`? Is there some way to install a package from PyPI with a custom `setup.py`?

Answer (score 0):

If the foo library is very popular and will be updated, install it with pip, if not, use the source code

Comment: foo is very popular, but when I install it with pip, it doesn't compile because of incorrect args to gcc. It does compile on most platforms, but I am running it on Cygwin and it doesn't compile there. That's the problem.